# how to build apk file from android studio?

Tags: android

When building apk file of a game from android studio I have this problem shown in this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUpjb.png)

Comment: Please do not post error messages (plain text) in a screen shot. Instead copy and paste it into your question and format it as code.

Comment: Chances are this is a compatibility problem between the gradle plugin, kotlin or other libraries. Try updating stuff.